# How can i mapped two columns and store it in temporary table MVC3 app with EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have created one MVC3 application.
In which I'm selecting two Ids from two different tables
which i need to map and need to save somewhere temporary and want to display at the end.

`I have taken two dropdownlist each one populated from one-one table. then i need to select one id from one and other from 2nd table when i clicked on map button it should have to create one temp table will show me two (values)columns what i have mapped just. how can i create temp table? using EF.`

`table1`

`SELECT  PriceID
FROM    Pricing`

```
PriceID
P111
P222
P333
```

`table2`

`SELECT  QueryID
FROM    QueryTable`

```
QueryID
Q565UUU
Q661YAA
Q421933
```

now i'm not getting how can I show them to select one-one Ids from each to map them together any help?

Mapped dataset or any temptable will have two columns

```
 PriceID  QueryID
  P111    Q565UUU
```

I'm newbie in MVC3 what should I take to show single columns ?

Please help need to create the UI so that one can easily select SecurityID and CUSIP from each table and map to each other..

what should i use?

Comment: hey why close? I just need to know which is better way to select ids from both tables so that one can map both them :(
grid , checkbox etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new model and populate it with your data and then use that model in your view:

```
namespace yourProject.ViewModels 
{ 
    public class PriceQueryGroup 
    { 
        public string PriceID { get; set; }      
        public string QueryID { get; set; } 
    } 
}
```

in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<yourProject.ViewModels.PriceQueryGroup>
```

I hope I have understood your question correctly and that this helps.

Comment: Hi, I have taken two dropdownlist each one populated from one-one table. then i need to select one id from one and other from 2nd table when i clicked on map button it should have to create one temp table will show me two (values)columns what i have mapped just. how can i create temp table? using EF.

Comment: it seems to me the answer I have already provided will do that for you, but can you give more information, please?

Comment: index.cshtml:
model Mapping.Models.mydataEntities1
using (Html.BeginForm()) {
Html.LabelFor(model=>model.table1, "table1id")
    <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("table1id", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.table1.Select()) --wrong plz suggest
        </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.table2, "id2")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("id2", String.Empty)
        </div>
how can i select only ID from both table into dropdwn  :(